# add header (content type:text/html; charset=utf-8) in link when user click in it in MS word OR MS excel OR PDF file

Tags: excel, hyperlink, header

When I write or insert link of my site like **http://example.com/admin/home** in MS word or Excel or pdf file and sent to user to click it, when user click on that link show error

```
Can not Download the information you requested
```

get error 500,

After many days I check it with **postMan** and check the header of this link -that return error 500- I see that don't have header (content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8) 
if I add this header manually and click on post link in **post man** it work 
it's mean when user click  on link in MS word to open a web page don't sent header with content-type and site does not open 
how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It make me confused , In one page I add FooterViewComponent and in

> FooterViewComponent/default.chtml

I change main footer of site with new footer in java script,

when i remove new footer every think work fine.